# Adding a Wildcard to PowerDNS

Tags: networking, dns

I'm trying to use a server on my network (in this test case a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian) as the DNS server for everyone on the network, so I can pick and choose a few websites they access on the internet and redirect/route all other traffic to an intranet site.

The problem is the "all other traffic" part.

I followed [this blog post](http://www.ducky-pond.com/posts/2013/Oct/how-to-setup-a-dns-server-with-powerdns-on-raspberry-pi/) to set up PowerDNS and for all domains I've manually entered, I have it working great. Where my problem lies, is that I want all other traffic to send the user to an intranet site (said intranet site also works fine with this PowerDNS setup).

I've been Googling and reading the PowerDNS guide for hours and have yet to figure out how to set up a wildcard to route all domains that are not explicitly added to the bind config file to my internal site.

I'm hoping someone here can either 1) tell me how to set up an effective wildcard for "all other traffic", or 2) Tell me that I'm doing things all wrong and that there's some other, more effective way to achieve what I'm trying to do.